Branding option not found in Clerk
I am building an application in Next.js with typescript where I am managing the user authentication like sign in and sign up using google account or any other recognized social media platforms with Clerk. Well, clerk makes it extremely simple and easy to integrate user management and auth using email and passwords, with its prebuilt components. After building the user auth system, I want to apply customization to my app using the branding feature under the customization configure category, like setting the logo and the icon of my app. However, I am not able to find the branding feature under the customization category on the Clerk application management page.
I think that branding feature is depreciated now, and hence any new or updated feature is in use. So how can I apply branding to my application?

It is shifted to your organization's settings.

Go to your organization's setting by clicking the settings icon

Scroll down and you will find the branding option as well as the upload logo option.




